# How i resolve write.table col.names needs specification error

Tags: r, shiny, write.table

I am running a code in R Shiny app and getting an error

```
Warning: Error in write.table: invalid 'col.names' specification
  1: runApp
```

I dont know how to solve it. I tried many things.

The write.table is mentioned in the code several times as

```r
write.table(annot.df$UniProt, file='uniprot.txt', quote=FALSE, sep='\t', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
    accannot.df <- read.table('uniprot.txt', quote='', sep='\t')
write.table(bm.cnames, file='pData.txt', col.names='Treatment', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep='\t')
write.table(annot.df$UniProt, file='uniprot.txt', quote=FALSE, sep='\t', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
    accannot.df <- read.table('uniprot.txt', quote='', sep='\t')
write.table(bm.cnames, file='pData.txt', col.names='Treatment', row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, sep='\t')
write.table(deAcc, file='normalizedMatrix.txt', quote=FALSE, sep='\t', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

So i dont know which is creating a problem and how to resolve it. Any suggestions

I am expecting a correction in the code

Comment: `annot.df$UniProt` looks like you're trying to write an individual column (not a frame or matrix), is that intended? (It's not _wrong_ or an error, just curious.)

Comment: I don't know if it's causing it for you, but I can reproduce your error with `write.table(NULL, col.names="quux")`. Since this is within a shiny app, that suggests that either (a) your reactive chain is firing when dependent data is not yet available, such as early in the app instantiation or just bad timing; or (b) something in your data-processing chain is returning a length-0 vector into `bm.cnames`. I suggest you read https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html, add `browser()` to your shiny app before each write, run it locally, and explore the environment when it could be failing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.